# Google sheets query formula with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheets query

=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,QUERY('.Data'!$A$2:$AC, "SELECT E, AB WHERE (B = 'test' and AB !='')"))

I am expecting that the query would select all columns where B is test and AB does not have anything. However it does not. Example data:

```
Column B (1st row) = test  
Column B (2nd row) = test  
Column B (3rd row) = smile  
  
Column E (1st row) = E1  
Column E (2nd row) = E2  
Column E (3rd row) = E3

Column AB (1st row) = AB1  
Column AB (2nd row) = ''  
Column AB (3rd row) = ''
```

I expect to get: E1 AB1

What I get is:

E1 AB1
E2

Also tried "is not null" but that did not work as well. I searched around but was not able to figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below `QUERY()` function then use `TEXTJOIN()`.

```
=QUERY(A:H,"select E, G where (B='test') and (G is not null)")
```

If you want to use not equal `!=` operator then use-

```
=QUERY(A:H,"select E, G where (B='test') and (G !='')")
```

And the join values-

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),QUERY(A:H,"select E, G where (B='test') and (G !='')"))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the solution but it did not work fully as expected. In your example, if you add a number into G3, for example 25, E2 will be added to the query result. E2 should not be added. Think you used JOIN in your formula instead of TEXTJOIN as well.

Comment: Funny enough E2 is not added if you use letters, only numbers. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @SystemWorks Because `every column can have only one type of literal: string or numeric (which contains numbers and date/time) values. If a given column includes more than one type of literal, then Google Sheets will pick the data type that is used more frequently for this column to execute the Query function on.` So you can try this formula `=JOIN(CHAR(10),QUERY(INDEX(TEXT(A:H,"@")),"select Col5,Col7 where (Col2='test') and (Col7 !='0')",0))`.

Comment: Or use `=JOIN(CHAR(10),QUERY(FILTER(A:H,B:B="test",G:G<>""),"select Col5, Col7"))` you can also use `TEXTJOIN()` but textjoin has character limitation may be `32762`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me get to what I wanted to do. The las comment was especially helpful.